# What are multiline items in Salesforce?

Tags: trigger

I am learning about triggers in Salesforce using [the](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) documentation.

It is said there:

> Salesforce runs user-defined validation rules if multiline items were created, such as quote line items and opportunity line items.

I can [not](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=multiline+items+salesforce&oq=multiline+items+salesforce&aqs=chrome.0.69i59.2617j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) find on the internet what is a multiline item in Salesforce. If possible tell me what it is in a nutshell or provide the resource to learn about it, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Opportunities, Quotes, Contracts and a few other objects like Orders each have what's called "line items". Since you can have more than one line item in these objects, they're referred to as "multi line items".

In order to get the total price of an Opportunity, you need to calculate the sum up the price from each line item. There can be validation rules related to products, prices, discounts and other things on each line item including things like the amount of a product in inventory or the production schedule to meet the Opportunity's delivery date.

If line items are created or modified in a trigger, validation rules will need to be run when the trigger finishes executing. Under normal circumstances, validation rules would run before the trigger is called.